# Can't understand. Is this a subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have something in a query that I have to edit, that I don't understand.

There are 4 tables that are joined: tickets, tasks, tickets_users, users. The whole query is not important, but you have an example at the end of the post. What bugs me is this kind of code used many times in relation to other tables:

```
(SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE users.id=tickets_users.users_id
) AS RequesterName,
```

Is this a subquery with the tables users and tickets_users joined? What is this?

```
WHERE users.id=tickets_users.users_id
```

If this was a join I would have expected to see:

```
ON users.id = tickets_users.users_id
```

And how is this different from a typical join? Just use the same column definition: *users.name* and just join with the users table.

Can anyone enlighten me on the advanced SQL querying prowess of the original author?

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    description,
    (SELECT name
     FROM users
     WHERE users.id = tickets_users.users_id) AS RequesterName,
    (SELECT description
     FROM tickets 
     WHERE tickets.id = ticket_tasks.tickets_id) AS TicketDescription,
    ticket_tasks.content AS TaskDescription
FROM 
    ticket_tasks
RIGHT JOIN 
    tickets ON ticket_tasks.tickets_id = tickets.id
INNER JOIN
    tickets_users ON tickets_users.tickets_id = tickettasks.tickets_id
```

Thanks,

Comment: If it was me, I'd start over.

Comment: yeah, that's a "dirty" way to get the result, but using join make it faster.

Comment: But what is that? A way to join another table without the standard joining definition?

Comment: That SQL seems to use a RIGHT JOIN, then an INNER JOIN against a column on the right side of the join. Seems to render that RIGHT JOIN to effectively be an INNER JOIN. Also it seems to get the description from the tickets table, then use a correlated sub query to get it again.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is called a [correlated subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html). To describe it in simple terms its doing a select inside a select.

However doing this more than once in ANY query is not recommended AT ALL.. the performance issue with this will be huge.

A correlated subquery will return a row by row comparison for each row of the select... if that doesnt make sense then think of it this way...

```
SELECT 
    id,
    (SELECT id FROM tableA AS ta WHERE ta.id > t.id)
FROM 
    tableB AS t;
```

This will do for each row in tableB, every row in tableA will be selected and compared to tableB id.

**NOTE:**

If you have 100 rows in all 4 tables and you do a correlated subquery for each one then you are doing 100*100*100*100 row comparisons. thats 100,000,000 (one hundred million) comparisons!

**A correlated subquery is NOT a join, but rather a subquery..**

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT id FROM t -- this is a subquery
    ) AS temp
```

However, JOINs are different... generally you can do it one of these two ways

This is the faster way

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t.id
```

This is the slower way

```
SELECT * 
FROM t, t1
WHERE t1.id = t.id
```

what the second join is doing is making the Cartesian Product of the two tables and then filtering out the extra stuff in the WHERE clause as opposed to the first JOIN that filters as it joins.

For the different types of joins theres a few and all are useful in their prospective actions..

- INNER JOIN (same as JOIN)
- LEFT JOIN
- RIGHT JOIN
- LEFT OUTER JOIN
- RIGHT OUTER JOIN

In mysql FULL JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN does not exist.. so in order to do a FULL join you need to combine a LEFT and RIGHT join. See this link for a better understanding of what joins do with Venn diagrams [LINK](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

**REMEMBER** this is for SQL so it includes the FULL joins as well. those don't work in MySQL.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks a lot. I remember, many years ago I used cursors in TS-SQL to do something similar. Very slow.

Comment: @user3856829 thanks.. see my edit for the different types of joins as well.. i included a link for a visual representation of them to help :)

Comment: @user3856829 if this solved your question please don't forget to accept it as the correct answer! :)